# MVC Logon just refreshes page - doesn't log on

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, shared-hosting, authentication

Hi
I have 2 MVC sites on a shared hosting environment.
 The first one works fine and I can log on and use the membership provider etc.. no problems. A second site can see the database and retrieve other (site specific) data on its pages. However when I try to log in I simply get a page refresh - no error messages with invalid UC/PW, and no succesful log on with good credentials, for example.

One further piece of info (may be a red herring) is that the first domain has the database declared within its control panel (using Plesk) - but the second one has no reference to it within the domain - however the hosting company have assured me that simply using the same connection string will work. And it does to retreive the site-specific data.
cheers
tm, Leeds UK

Comment: Do u care your question be read before answered? Then, edit your post with paragraphs (line breaks)

Answer (score 0):

For anyones interest .  .
It seems that because the site was still in preview, forms don't work until you actually put live.
Hosting is with Storm Internet